# Identity pool not being given permissions I specify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have an aws identity pool set up with the following policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I try to call the 'getuser' method, I get the following error:

```
AccessDenied: User: {/*the identitypool*/} is not authorized to perform: iam:GetUser on resource: user foo
```

Here's the code:

```
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: 'my user pool id' });

    var iam = new AWS.IAM({ apiVersion: '2010-05-08' });
    var params = {
      UserName: "foo"
    };
    iam.getUser(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err && err.code === 'NoSuchEntity') {
        console.log("no such entity");
      } else {
        console.log("err, data", err, data);
      }
```

What am I missing? I'm pretty new to AWS, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the Enhanced flow. You must enable the basic authentication flow in your Identity pool. I'm not really sure about the code (not a JS guy), but if you are using the unauth role, this is the reason behind the error.

"For additional security protection, Amazon Cognito applies a scope-down policy to credentials vended by GetCredentialForIdentity to prevent access to majority of services for your unauthenticated users."

Have a look at the doc here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html#access-policies